# Is it possible to retrieve a single application from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I've got a Time Machine backup from an old machine.

I don't want to over-write all the content from the backup, I'd just like to retrieve a couple of applications that were on my old machine - TextMate and Microsoft Word.

Is it possible to retrieve those applications singly, without over-writing all the content on my new machine?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just mount your backup as a disk and copy the files you want out of it.

Comment: You may need to dig a bit deeper for Word to get it's prefs and other associated files. I'm not sure how much it sprays into the System folder but some of that stuff may be useful in reestablishing it on the new drive. Textmate should run just fine although any bundles and prefs will need to be moved separately.